# Hibernate Ehcache not using cached data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I'm trying to get ehcache working in a non Spring environment (Swing Client with Hibernate Entity Manager).

The cache seems to work, but for any reason the cache is sending all queries to the DB instead of using the cached values.

But I don't know why.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is my environment:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.38</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

ehcache.xml

> ```
>  <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
>             monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
>
>          <defaultCache
>                 maxElementsInMemory="10000"
>                 eternal="false"
>                 timeToIdleSeconds="120"
>                 timeToLiveSeconds="120"
>                 overflowToDisk="false"
>                 diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
>                 diskPersistent="false"
>                 diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
>                 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
>                 />
>     </ehcache>
> ```

persistence.xml

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
>     <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
>       version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
>
>       <persistence-unit name="jaccount" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Account</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.AccountId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Booking</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.BookingId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Category</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.CategoryId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Property</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Type</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Year</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.YearId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.I18n</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.I18nGroup</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.I18nItem</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Language</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.User</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.UserId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Payment</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.UserType</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.PaymentId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.PropertyId</class>
>           <class>ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.UserTypeId</class>
>
>           <properties>
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jaccount_test" />
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jaccount_test" />
>               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="testpw" />
>
>               <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
>
>               <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path"
>                   value="ehcache.xml" />
>               <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
>                   value="true" />
>               <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
>               <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
>                   value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
>               <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider" />
>               <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
>           </properties>
>
>       </persistence-unit>
>     </persistence>
> ```

Customer.java

```
@Entity
@Cache(region = "customer", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "custermer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(name = "customer_name", nullable = false)
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "customer_descr")
    private String customerDescripton;

    @Column(name = "customer_selected", nullable = false)
    private Boolean selected;

    public Long getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getCustomerDescripton() {
        return this.customerDescripton;
    }

    public void setCustomerDescripton(String customerDescripton) {
        this.customerDescripton = customerDescripton;
    }

    public Boolean getSelected() {
        return this.selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

Test

```
package ch.bemar.account.test.persistence;

import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.junit.Test;

import ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer;

public class CacheTest2 {

    // private MyEntityManager persistenceEngine;

    @Test
    public void testRaw() {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jaccount");
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();


        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();

        String hql = "from Customer";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setCacheable(true);

        Iterator it = query.list().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Customer account = (Customer) it.next();
            System.out.println(account);
        }

        query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setCacheable(true);

        it = query.list().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Customer account = (Customer) it.next();
            System.out.println(account);
        }

        System.out.println(commaToCr(session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics()));
    }

    private String commaToCr(Object text) {
        return StringUtils.replace(text.toString(), ",", "\n");
    }
}
```

Test Output

```
 HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
    HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
    No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/C:/Users/bemar/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.3/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
    Configuring ehcache from URL: jar:file:/C:/Users/bemar/.m2/repository/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache-core/2.4.3/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
    Configuring ehcache from InputStream
    Ignoring ehcache attribute xmlns:xsi
    Ignoring ehcache attribute xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
    Disk Store Path: C:\Users\bemar\AppData\Local\Temp\
    propertiesString is null.
    No CacheManagerEventListenerFactory class specified. Skipping...
    No BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class specified. Skipping...
    CacheWriter factory not configured. Skipping...
    No CacheExceptionHandlerFactory class specified. Skipping...
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [year]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file year.data
    Initialised cache: year
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'year'.
    started EHCache region: year
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [language]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file language.data
    Initialised cache: language
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'language'.
    started EHCache region: language
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [language]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [type]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file type.data
    Initialised cache: type
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'type'.
    started EHCache region: type
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [type]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [i18n]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file i18n.data
    Initialised cache: i18n
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'i18n'.
    started EHCache region: i18n
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [i18n]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [property]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file property.data
    Initialised cache: property
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'property'.
    started EHCache region: property
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [property]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [account]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file account.data
    Initialised cache: account
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'account'.
    started EHCache region: account
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [account]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [user_type]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file user_type.data
    Initialised cache: user_type
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'user_type'.
    started EHCache region: user_type
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [user_type]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [i18n_group]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file i18n_group.data
    Initialised cache: i18n_group
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'i18n_group'.
    started EHCache region: i18n_group
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [i18n_group]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [category]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file category.data
    Initialised cache: category
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'category'.
    started EHCache region: category
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [category]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [i18n_item]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file i18n_item.data
    Initialised cache: i18n_item
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'i18n_item'.
    started EHCache region: i18n_item
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [i18n_item]
    HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [customer]; using defaults.
    Deleting data file customer.data
    Initialised cache: customer
    CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for 'customer'.
    started EHCache region: customer
    HHH020007: read-only cache configured for mutable entity [customer]
    Hibernate: select customer0_.custermer_id as custerme1_3_, customer0_.customer_descr as customer2_3_, customer0_.customer_name as customer3_3_, customer0_.customer_selected as customer4_3_ from customer customer0_
    ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer@62b2a4
    ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer@dbd080
    Hibernate: select customer0_.custermer_id as custerme1_3_, customer0_.customer_descr as customer2_3_, customer0_.customer_name as customer3_3_, customer0_.customer_selected as customer4_3_ from customer customer0_
    ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer@62b2a4
    ch.bemar.account.persistence.model.Customer@dbd080
    Statistics[start time=1488717305688
    sessions opened=1
    sessions closed=0
    transactions=0
    successful transactions=0
    optimistic lock failures=0
    flushes=0
    connections obtained=1
    statements prepared=2
    statements closed=0
    second level cache puts=2
    second level cache hits=0
    second level cache misses=0
    entities loaded=2
    entities updated=0
    entities inserted=0
    entities deleted=0
    entities fetched=0
    collections loaded=0
    collections updated=0
    collections removed=0
    collections recreated=0
    collections fetched=0
    naturalId queries executed to database=0
    naturalId cache puts=0
    naturalId cache hits=0
    naturalId cache misses=0
    naturalId max query time=0
    queries executed to database=2
    query cache puts=0
    query cache hits=0
    query cache misses=0
    update timestamps cache puts=0
    update timestamps cache hits=0
    update timestamps cache misses=0
    max query time=35]
```

Thank you for your help

Benjamin

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />` This is in your `persistence.xml`, so it is disabled, or I am missing something.

Comment: A cache does not "send all queries to DB"; a cache replies if it has an object or not. A persistence provider is the only thing that sends queries to a DB

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thats quite embarrassing. After I turned the query cache on by

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
```

it worked.

Thanks guys.